# How to have full-screen despite the notch?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want an activity to be fullscreen despite the notch so that at its sides the screen is useful. Please does anyone know how to do it?

I guess it must be a different theme or something like that.
[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout/  refer this link

Comment: I've already read it but i don't know exactly what to do. Could you tell me please?

Answer (score 2):

There is a fix for this given by Android Pie Apis.
Follow the following steps:-

1) Create a new values-v28 folder in your res directory and copy the default styles.xml file into it.
Create new or edit existing theme

```
    <style name="ActivityTheme">
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
    shortEdges
    </item>
    </style>
```

There are 3 possible values for android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode ie - default,shortEdges and never . Try each to know the difference between them .

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work because a problem appears. Look at the picture i've left on the post above.

Comment: Have you created values-v28 ? . Try Invalidate Cache and Restart because i never faced such error and most of the times this kind of errors are bogus .

Answer (score 1):

Doing this programmaticaly inside a activity which is what worked for me instead of defining a style will be as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
    }
```

This code is what changes the whole scenario for devices with notch display

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
    }
```

Also, if by any chance you still see the system ui the use the following code along with the above code

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this in your activity

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

This makes the activity full screen by removing navigation and status bars